# How to access the parameter being validated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the following example, is there a way to retrieve the name of the parameter being currently validated inside the if proc ?

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options if: proc{|o| "how to retreive the parameter being validated here?"} do
    validates :param_1, presence: true
    validates :param_2, presence: true
  end
end
```

I would like to avoid this kind of solution:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :param_1, presence: true, if: proc{|o| o.need_validation?(:param_1)}
  validates :param_2, presence: true, if: proc{|o| o.need_validation?(:param_2)}
end
```

Comment: What is the name that you need? Is that an attribute of `o`?

Comment: `proc{|o| o.param_1 == true }`

Comment: I need to know which parameter is being validated, something that would return `:param_1` or `'param_1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no easy answer to my question, I'll find an other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to know name, and other data like option to validation, use validators:

**app/validators/param_validator.rb**:

```
ParamValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
   def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      # your validation code here...
   end
end
```

The arguments say about themself.

Use it in a model:

```
validates :param_1, param: true
validates :param_2, param: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If each of the validations are identical apart from the name, you could iterate over them:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  [:param1,:param2].each do |param|
    validates param, presence: true, if: proc{|o| o.need_validation?(param) }
  end
end
```